# Is there any open source alternative to Google Docs?

Tags: open-source, google-docs

I'm looking for an Open Source alternative to Google Docs. Reason I want it is because I want to host it on my computer. Google doesn't allow you to do that. 
Anyone know of any open source alternatives to Google Docs? I would be grateful if there were any.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can refer to this URL, it may be what you want https://github.com/benjamn/kix-standalone/tree/master/js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FengOffice](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/features.php) has some overlap, though not as far as I can see, spreadsheets, and although they push their paid for product, are [open source](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/community/why-is-open-source.php).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)?

Comment: I need web office, many thanks!

Comment: LibreOffice online is now available which is a web solution - https://owncloud.documentfoundation.org/public.php?service=files&t=e988c37eded954bdbceea0bdafcf130a

Answer (score 1):

There is also eyeOS:
http://www.eyeos.com/

eyeOS is an open-source cloud desktop with office applications.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Chrome does have an Offline Docs plugin. This would enable you to set up offline access to Google Drive on your computer. Here is the link for setting this up:

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375012

With that being said, OpenOffice is also a good option. It just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst the link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. :)

Comment: Thank u very much, I had developed a similar website as Google Docs yet:)But saddly, we have no chance to launch it. The Project is canceled(only work with doc file)